# Showing that some vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$. For $j, k \in \{1,...,n\}$, $j \neq k$, let $\rho_{jk} \geq 0$ such that $\sum_{k=1, k \neq j}^n \rho_{jk} >0$ for all $j=1,...,n$. We define the vectors $(e^j)_{j=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ by $e^j(j):=-\sum_{k=1, k \neq j}^n \rho_{jk}$ and $e^j(k):=\rho_{jk}$ for $j, k \in \{1,...,n-1\}$, $k \neq j$.

I want to show that the set of vectors $(e^j-e^n)_{j=1}^{n-1}$ is linearly independent. This is easy to prove if $n \leq 3$, but is hard to generalize the proof to an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is it possible for you to accept some answers? Also what have you done for $n\leq 3$? At the moment I don't think that you'll receive an answer.

Comment: If $n=2$, then $e^1=-\rho_{12}$ and $e^2=\rho_{21}$, so $e^1-e^2=-\rho_{12}-\rho_{21}<0$, and then $a_1(e^1-e^2)=0$ if and only if $a_1=0$.

Comment: If $n=3$, then $e^1=(-\rho_{12}-\rho_{13},\rho_{12})$, $e^2=(\rho_{21},-\rho_{21}-\rho_{23})$, $e^3=(\rho_{31}, \rho_{32})$, which implies $e^1-e^3=(-\rho_{12}-\rho_{13}-\rho_{31},\rho_{12}-\rho_{32})$ and $e^2-e^3=(\rho_{21}-\rho_{31},-\rho_{21}-\rho_{23}-\rho_{32})$. If we suppose that $a_1(e^1-e^3)+a_2(e^2-e^3)=\vec{0}$, then the following equations must be satisfied $a_1(-\rho_{12}-\rho_{13}-\rho_{31})+b(\rho_{12}-\rho_{32})=0=a_2(-\rho_{21}-\rho_{23}-\rho_{32})+a_1(\rho_{21}-\rho_{31})$.

Comment: If we multiply the first equality by $\rho_{21}-\rho_{31})$ and the second by $-\rho_{12}-\rho_{13}-\rho_{31}$, we obtain $a_2[\rho_{21}(\rho_{13}+\rho_{31}+\rho_{32})+\rho_{23}(\rho_{12}+\rho_{13}+\rho_{31})+\rho_{32}(\rho_{12}+\rho_{13}+\rho_{21})+\rho_{31}\rho_{12}+\rho_{32}\rho_{21}]=0$. By assumption, we have $\rho_{13}+\rho_{31}+\rho_{32} \geq \rho_{31}+\rho_{32}>0$ and $\rho_{12}+\rho_{13}+\rho_{31} \geq \rho_{12}+\rho_{13}>0$. Also $\rho_{21}>0$ or $\rho_{23}>0$, which implies that the right part in the previous equation multiplying $a_2$, is strictly positive, so $a_2=0$.

Comment: Then $a_1(-\rho_{12}-\rho_{13}-\rho_{31})=0$. Since $\rho_{12}+\rho_{13}+\rho_{31}>0$, we conclude that $a_1=0$.

Comment: If we define $\rho_{jj}=0$, which is the same as the condition $k\neq j$, for $n=N$, I've reduced each of the $N-1$ components to this:

$$\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(a^i\rho_{ik}-a^{k}\rho_{ki})-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}a^i\right)\rho_{Nk} -a^k\rho_{kN}= 0\right]_{k=1}^{N-1}$$

From here we may deduce some things and maybe prove that they're l.i.

Comment: Maybe I'd try to group all $\rho$s in each $a^i$ and then solve a system of equations via Cramer.

Comment: I got this:
$$\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}a^i(\rho_{ik}-\rho_{Nk})-a^k\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\rho_{ki}\right)+\rho_{Nk}\right] = 0\right]_{k=1}^{N-1}$$

Comment: What's left is analyzing
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-\left(\sum \rho_{1i}\right)-\rho_{N1} & \rho_{21}-\rho_{N1}& \dots & \rho_{(N-1)1}-\rho_{N1}\\
\rho_{12}-\rho_{N2} & -\left(\sum \rho_{2i}\right)-\rho_{N2} & \dots & \rho_{(N-1)2}-\rho_{N2}\\
&\vdots &\\
\rho_{1(N-1)}-\rho_{N(N-1)}&\rho_{2(N-1)}-\rho_{N(N-1)}&\dots &-\left(\sum \rho_{(N-1)i}\right)-\rho_{N(N-1)}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\mathbf 0$$

Comment: If its determinant is $\neq 0$, then they are linearly independent.